# Date field Start and End limit

Tags: datetime

When we create a date field in node form, we can set START and END years to be shown in that date field.
If we are creating a date field programatcaly, how do we do that?

I have a date field, `my_date`, I want to to show only next 5 years from now on.
Any help?

```
$form['my_date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#date_format' => 'd-m-y',
  '#default_value' => format_date($primary_start1, 'custom', $format),
  '#date_type' => DATE_DATETIME,
  '#date_timezone' => date_default_timezone(),
  '#date_format' => 'm/d/Y',
  '#size' => 20,
  '#access' => TRUE,
);
```

I tried to see structure bu creating a date field and printing the form, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

We can do it like this...

```
$form['my_date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#date_format' => 'd-m-y',
  '#default_value' => format_date($primary_start1, 'custom', $format),
  '#date_type' => DATE_DATETIME,
  '#date_timezone' => date_default_timezone(),
  '#date_format' => 'm/d/Y',
  '#size' => 20,
  '#access' => TRUE,
  '#after_build' => array("custom_range_date")
);
```

using `'#after_build' => array("custom_range_date")`

```
function custom_range_date($form_element, &$form_state){
    // We unset the current values
    unset($form_element['year']['#options']);

    // Now we set the range we want
    $max_age = date('Y') - 100; // 100 years ago
    $min_age = date('Y') - 7; // 7 years ago

    // Now we populate the array
    $form_element['year']['#options'] = array();
    foreach (range($max_age, $min_age) as $year){
        $form_element['year']['#options'][$year] = $year;
    }

    // We return our modified element
    return $form_element;
}
```

SEE: https://www.drupal.org/node/1165138